# Migrate a BEA 8.1 Web Service project to Eclipse

Tags: web-services, wsdl, ejb, migration, weblogic

I have a kind of a "giant" web service built with SOAP, EJB 2.1 and we use BEA WebLogic Platform 8.1 as IDE. 
It is a critical web service, used by different countries and it access more than 15 data sources to generate a XML with some information.

We want to migrate the application to use a better IDE for development like Eclipse,  and we also want to use a dependency managment tool like maven and add a dependency injection framework like Spring.

The project is divided in a main web service project and some other project with EJB 2.1 used to extract information of some data sources.

What would be the best way to migrate this project, without breaking the interface(wsdl) of the web service?

Any help or hint is welcome.

Comment: You're not migrating to a new version of weblogic? The end of life for weblogic 8.x was 2008... so it's going to be difficult to find any answers. That said, I'm not sure why you would have any problems using Maven or Spring as long as you use a version that supports EJB2.1. The WSDL itself should not need to change. Have you had any specific problems? What have you tried?

Comment: We want to deploy the development environment, the production application is deployed over weblogic 11g now. But we are still using BEA 8.1 to develop.

Comment: A recent team tried to migrate it to Eclipse, but the project didnt worked as expected. The application who access the web service didnt reconized the version of the WSDL, i think they made a mistake at this point. We are going to try migrate it again now using new and upgraded stack of technologies, using the same code.

Comment: We want to keep the same interface to whoever access the web service. The WSDL version cannot be changed and JAX-RPC too. But we want to use Spring, maven and Java 1.6.

Comment: Are people accessing the interface using java 1.4? That's what 8.x uses. It sounds like you have a difficult project, not sure I can help without more details on the problems you have encountered - good luck

Comment: Yes, they access it by a client version 1.6.